# Create and Update JSON calls not working

Tags: angularjs, json, json-server

I am learning Angular 2 and have an interesting issue.  I am using json-server to mock my service calls and retrieve works well.  However I have issues with Create and Update.

I am using a basic model called notification which looks like so:-

```
export class NotificationModel {
constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public description: string
){}
```

}

and here's my basic functions nothing too strange here!

```
createNotification(notification : NotificationModel) {  
    return this._http.post('http://{myurl}/notifications', JSON.stringify(notification))
        .map(res => res.json());
}

updateNotification(notification : NotificationModel) {
    return this._http.put('http://{myurl}/notifications/' + notification.id, JSON.stringify(notification))
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

When I try to pass in simple test values I instead get the following:-

The create generates a 9 character alphanumeric value for id and nothing in the other fields.
Here's my object:-

```
{"id":5,"name":"NEW NOTIFICATION","description":"NEW NOTIFICATION DESCRIPTION"}
```

**UPDATE**:- Here's what it creates

```
{
  "id": "rkxCLjZLx"
}
```

The update blanks out the other two fields and just keeps the id field.
Here's my object

```
{"id":"3","name":"Notification 3","description":"UPDATE DESCRIPTION"}
```

**UPDATE**:- Here's the record after update

```
{
  "id": "3"
}
```

Is this a json-server issue or is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here's the functions I use to call my service

```
addNotification(notification : NotificationModel) {
    this._notificationService.createNotification(new NotificationModel(5,
                                    'NEW NOTIFICATION', 'NEW NOTIFICATION DESCRIPTION')).subscribe(
         data => {
           // refresh the list
           this._notificationService.getNotifications().subscribe(res => {
                    this.notifications = res;
                }
            );
           return true;
         },
         error => {
           console.error("Error adding notification!");
           return Observable.throw(error);
         }
      );
}

updateNotification(notification : NotificationModel) {

    notification.description = 'UPDATE DESCRIPTION';

    this._notificationService.updateNotification(notification).subscribe(
         data => {
           // refresh the list
           this._notificationService.getNotifications().subscribe(res => {
                    this.notifications = res;
                }
            );
           return true;
         },
         error => {
           console.error("Error updating notification!");
           return Observable.throw(error);
         }
      );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the new notifications? Also can you clarify the test values, I'm confused as to what is the expected vs actual.

Comment: Added more information to my question

Comment: what does the network tab in your browser's developer tools show for the http requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue!

I wasn't setting the content type anywhere! By updating my PUT and POST requests like so it now works as expected.

```
createNotification(notification : NotificationModel) {

    let body = JSON.stringify(notification);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });         

    return this._http.post(this.serviceURL, body, options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}

updateNotification(notification : NotificationModel) {

    let body = JSON.stringify(notification);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

    return this._http.put(this.serviceURL + '/' + notification.id, body, options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```